# Gravity Forms Error removing jquery setting

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a jquery script which appends an option value to a dropdown field created in Gravity Forms for Wordpress.

The problem I am facing is that as soon as a form error loads lets say you enetered a wrong email in the email field the append values dissapear from the dropdown. As soon as I refresh the page they re-appear.

Hope I am making sense.

Here is the script I am using to append the fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#input_3_2").append("<option>Male</option>");
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just add the option value from within Gravity Forms?

Comment: Because its a custom field area which its created in the template between content which changes accordign to the user choice. Since its dynamic I wanted jquery to capture that information then insert it in the gravity forms field which is sent to the client. This works the only issue i have is the error text which loads with ajax i think so i need to either disable ajax or find an alternative solution which is why I am here. Thanks

Comment: Ok solved the problem by outputting the form in html5, not a perfect solution but it works. :)

Comment: It would still be good to know how to fix an issue like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this issue is to use the gravity forms event `gform_post_render`
like this:

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render',function(){ 
  /* Add Form Field Here */ $("#input_3_2").append("<option>Male</option>");
})
```